# Sum of price of products using only Reduce(callback)

Tags: arrays, callback, reduce

I want the sum of prices from this array:

```
const products = [
  { product: 'banana', price: 3 },
  { product: 'mango', price: 6 },
  { product: 'potato', price: ' ' },
  { product: 'avocado', price: 8 },
  { product: 'coffee', price: 10 },
  { product: 'tea', price: '' },
]
```

the code I am trying is:

```
const sum = products.reduce((price, pri) => price+pri, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

also, how can I get the largest numbers among the values, I tried filter and forEach but don't understand where I am going wrong, could anyone share the code with me so that I can extract the largest number

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
I changed the "''" to 0 otherwise it would concatenate the values.
On your code, it's missing the value for each element[price].

```
  const products = [
    { product: 'banana', price: 3 },
    { product: 'mango', price: 6 },
    { product: 'potato', price: 0 },
    { product: 'avocado', price: 8 },
    { product: 'coffee', price: 10 },
    { product: 'tea', price: 0 },
  ]

  let sum = products.reduce((previousValue, currentProduct) => {
    return previousValue + currentProduct.price
  }, 0);

  console.log('result: ', sum)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks exactly what I wanted and needed to know, the output I was getting was concatenated only, also could you help me out with the next question as well?